# How can I synchronize access to stored data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, thread-safety

I am using Google App Engine with the Python 2.7 run time. I know it is multi-threaded, but the multi-instance nature of Google App Engine makes this question relevant to any run time.

I have a web messenger application. It is based on the Channel API for receiving various notifications (message received, user connected, user typed) and on the Memcache API for maintaining global state (and on the High Replication Datastore for actually storing the message history).
The time stamp of the last message is kept in Memcache (along with other data, such whether the user is online or not, typing or not and others).
Whenever a user sends a message, the Memcache is updated with the new time stamp value, while the old time stamp value is sent using the Channel API.
When multiple messages are sent at the same time, the Memcache is sometimes overwritten and I get weird values for that time stamp. For example -
One message has a certain time stamp and the ***next*** has an ***older*** time stamp.

I know about the Memcache Client API, but I cannot use that because I must read the most up to date time stamp first and the write the new time stamp.

In short, I want to somehow wait for the (Memcache?) data to be completely unoccupied (read or write), lock it somehow, proceed throughout the entire request and then release it for the next request.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Memcache isn't designed for what you're trying to use it for. Remember, it's a cache, not a persistent storage mechanism. What are you actually trying to achieve as an end result?

Comment: You won't overload the datastore as long as you don't restrict everything to a small set of entity groups. Have you considered pull queues, though? It's difficult to be more specific without more information about exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Every time someone is sending a message (which can happen few times per second), I am taking the old value, storing the message in the database, announcing the message (and the old value) using the Channel API to all of the related users and only if everything (storing and announcing) succeeded, I store the new value. Queues are not appropriate here, because I need these operations to happen in real time. Do you need any other information? (please, also read the thread between me and Adam Thomason below)

Comment: The old value of what? And what constitutes the set of 'related users'? And pull queues are real time - as soon as you insert an item into the queue, it can be pulled out by another process.

Comment: The old value is the time stamp of the last sent/received message. Related users are the sender and the recipient of the message. Pull queues are not much of a help here, because this may still overload the database due to too many operations at once...

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit locking functionality in the Memcache API, but you can achieve the effect using the [Compare-and-Set](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_cas) mechanism. Guido has a writeup with examples [here](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html). Only the Client class exposes CAS, though, but it's unclear from your description why that won't work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Yeah, I know about the compare and set (that is what I meant by referring to the Memcache Client API, sorry).
I need to use the latest value from the Memcache, save the message to the database, send the value using the Channel API and then store the new value in the Memcache. This must be one synchronous and blocking operation.
I can use something other than the Memcache API, if you have any suggestion that may fit.

Comment: It sounds like you need a proper transactional mechanism, which memcache doesn't support. Have you already tried using datastore transactions instead and if so, what didn't work for you?

Comment: I did not try it, because I am afraid of overloading the database. This operation is happening all of the time... is there any other solution?

Comment: You only need to be concerned with overloading the datastore if you are updating the same entity more than a handful of times per second. Assuming you store your state per-user, an instant messaging application is unlikely to exceed that in the steady state (i.e., automatic retries will make things work on average even with occasional spikes). I would recommend you try it out and ask other questions if you encounter particular problems. Also take a look at the articles [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/overview) for scaling tips.

Comment: Actually, I am updating the same entity currently, but I am mainly doing that because I always need all of this information (or none of it) and Memcache can delete some of the keys (the not recently used), so I just use an "application-data" key and put everything there.

Comment: Unfortunately here is no available API that supports both transactional and high frequency updates. You'll need to either 1) reimplement locking and retries with CAS or 2) shard your data to distribute the updates across entities. (1) reduces but does not eliminate the possibility of inconsistency because your lock key may be evicted unpredictably. (2) requires you to reconsider your data model.

Comment: If you _really_ need global state, you could adapt the [sharding counters strategy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) and include a timestamp with each state change. To get the latest update you could gather the updates from every shard and use only the most recent. By adjusting the number of shards you'll always be able to scale sufficiently, but you'll blow through quota much faster.

Comment: I think my general approach is wrong... counting on the various APIs for that... I worked around it for now by re-fetching the last messages from the older time stamp again. Thank you.

Comment: Which obviously did not help. Too bad my entire approach is wrong and I have to refactor the whole thing.